# Can I get getImgData using base64 string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I have a base64 string. Is there any way I can get `ctx.getImageData();` from the base64 string? If yes, please guide me.

Comment: Sure, just draw the image in a canvas

Comment: how can i do that? please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to create a canvas, and then draw the image in the canvas to get pixel information from `getImageData()`

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx    = canvas.getContext("2d");
var image  = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    ctx.getImageData(50, 50, 100, 100);
};
image.src = "data:image/png;base64,...";
```